# Any way to rewrite/simplify $\int dp ~f(p)~\delta[c-g(p)-E(p)]$?

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, quantum-mechanics, dirac-delta

Im thinking of using $$\delta(g(x)) = \sum_i \frac{\delta(x-x_i)}{|g'(x_i)|}$$ but in my case $$\int dp ~f(p)~\delta[c-g(p)-E(p)]$$ 
the functions $f$ and $E$ are basically unknown, while $g$ is a simple square root function and $c$ a constant.  Simplifying

Comment: there is no reason why you shouldn't use your first for,ula

Comment: But what about the unknown functions and their zeroes etc?